# Create an online eclipse update site from local plugin folder

Tags: java, eclipse, http, eclipse-plugin, update-site

I developed my first eclipse plugin. I first exported the project as a deploybale feature, generating a folder containing: artifacts.jar, content.jar, and the plugins and features folders. 
I tested the plugin locally by going to "install new software" then specifying the **local plugin folder** and it works after installation.

Now my question is **how to create an online update site (from my local plugin folder)** that I can give to other people to test the plugin on their machines?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The folder containing the `artifacts.jar` file, `content.jar` file and the `plugins` and `features` folders is already an update site which can be copied to a static web server so it can be accessed via HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you now need to make that folder available on a web or ftp server and give users that URL that they use when going to eclipse -> install new software where they will paste the URL of your update site that works locally for you.